# Google App Engine - Add Email API authorized senders from Domain Alias

Tags: email, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine app, with two custom domains (let's say, for example, `a.com` and `b.com`).

Domain `b.com` is a Google App alias for `a.com` i.e. Under Google Apps Admin Console -> Domains -> Add/Remove Domains `b.com` is listed as "Domain alias for a.com".

I would like our app to be able to send email from our AppEngine app from addresses at `b.com`, as in `me@b.com` or an email alias like `alias@b.com`.  The documentation indicates that it is possible, but it does not work as documented or I have overlooked something.

If I try to send email with the [App Engine Mail api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) from `me@b.com` or `alias@b.com` I get the error of "InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender."

The remedy for this would seem to be, as the title of this question suggests, to add authorized senders under:

> Cloud Console -> App Engine -> Settings -> Application Settings -> Email API authorized senders

When I attempt to add e.g. `me@a.com` it is added to the list of authorized senders, as expected.  When I attempt to add `me@b.com`, `alias@a.com` or `alias@b.com` it fails.

The specific error I get from Cloud Console when I attempt to add the addresses is:

> **Unable to add authorized senders**
>
> You don't have permission to add these users to the authorized senders list. [Learn more](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/?hl=en_US&_ga=1.149109686.1473319548.1456418313)

Following the above link, the relevant bit about permissions would be:

> ... a message must be sent by ...
>
> - Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under Email API Authorized Senders
>
> ...
>
> ... domain administrators of domains managed by Google Apps can add any user in their domain to the list.
>
> If you have one or more aliases set up for your Google Apps domain, you can send email from email addresses that use the domain alias.  For example, adding "xyz@domain.com" to the Authorized Senders list will have the effect of also allowing sending email from "xyz@alias.com".

The document notes that SPF records must be properly configured as the documentation indicates, and they are, namely:

```
$ dig a.com txt
...
a.com.      604556  IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
...

$ dig b.com txt
...
b.com.      604556  IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
...
```

Although not necessary, DKIM has been configured from all the domains, and all the MX records point to Google Apps.

Under Google Apps Admin Console -> Users -> Me -> Account -> Aliases the following are among those listed (among others):

- me@b.com
- alias@a.com
- alias@b.com

So the question would be: What, if anything, am I overlooking here that is either a.) preventing sending from the domain aliases and/or b.) preventing sending from the alias email addresses in general?  If I hae not overlooked something, what recourse may follow?

As an aside, a workaround would be to use a third party mailer e.g. Mandrill, MailGun, or SendGrid. Those are overkill, a hassle, and unnecessary complexity for what is a very simple use case on our end, so a solution over AppEngine would be ideal.

Comment: From what i read it sounds like you are Google Apps admin and you are trying to send as one of your aliases. While that should be possible since you're also application owner I can imagine that Google might want to prevent you from sending emails as Google Apps admin. Could be worth a try and attempt this with a "normal" Google Apps user account. Also: Is your Google Apps Domain a paid one (GApps for Business) or are you using the free version (which doesn't exist anymore)?

Comment: @konqi – Thanks for the comment.  It is an admin account, and it is indeed the free version.  Interesting points.

Comment: The free version could be the issue here, there are a lot of features that we (i have a free version myself) don't get. If i find the time on the weekend i'll try and set this up on my domain. If that doesn't work I can do the same with a paid domain, see if that makes the difference.

Comment: Awesome– many thanks, @konqi.  I am tinkering as well and will report any progress/remedy.

Comment: Incidentally, as a work-around I have signed up for Postmark (https://postmarkapp.com/) for transactional email of the sort I would have otherwise sent with the Google mail API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by using [PostMark](https://postmarkapp.com/).

There are a number of other solid options, including SendGrid, Mailgun, Mandrilla, MailChimp, and others.

We settled on PostMark because it has an agreeable templating system and focuses on transactional email deliverability.